# TabBar not showing using xamarin.forms Shell

Tags: c#, xamarin.forms, xamarin.forms.shell

I'm creating a new xamarin.forms application and want to implement Shell to navigate around the app.

I have created a blank xamarin.forms app and have added an AppShell.xaml.

The Xaml looks like this:

```
<TabBar>
    <Tab>
        <ShellContent ContentTemplate="{DataTemplate views:FoodEntriesPage}" Title="Hello"/>
    </Tab>
</TabBar>
```

And the .cs file looks like this:

```
public partial class AppShell : Shell
    {
        public AppShell()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }
    }
```

I have then changed the MainPage to be a new instance of my AppShell in App.Xaml.cs like this:

```
public App()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            MainPage = new AppShell();
        }
```

My issue is that the TabBar is not displaying at the bottom of the screen. If I were to add a flyout menu, the three dots to indicate it's there show but there is no visible tabs to click on.

I have followed guides that show how to implement shell into existing and new applications but even if I follow step by step it doesn't work for me where it works for them. What am i doing wrong?

Comment: have you tried using the App Shell template instead of the blank template and comparing them?

Comment: I've tried using both templates that have it pre-set, they're displayed in that instance but any attempt to add a Flyout in the tabbed template and a tab menu in the flyout template doesn't work.

Comment: Are your tabs same level of navigation as the flyout items, or they are the sub-level menus?

Comment: They're the same level I think, I'll just add them directly below (For different navigation types). But I just want one to work starting from a blank template.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Using just on tab bar results in a single page with no navigation. And then adding multiple shellcontent into one tab results in a top-side tab bar.

Adding multiple tabs at the same level inside the tabbar creates a bottom bar and solved my issue.